# Removing `else` condition suddenly makes the code work, what gives?

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

This code doesn't do as intended - it should print out all of plaintext. I'm guessing there's something at work under the hood, but that logic escapes me. If you remove the `else` condition with underlying statement, it suddenly works.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if(isalpha(plaintext[i] != 0))
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        //I intend to do stuff with alphabetic characters, but that code isn't relevant, so it's not included
        else
            printf("%c", 'a');
}
```

I'll be honest, this looks like magic to me. Why would adding an `else` condition affect whether the condition for the original `if` statement was met or not (if that's the case)?

Is it somehow because of using string in cs50.h?

Comment: what do you input, what do you see with else, what do you see without else?

Comment: @DavidRanieri I have solutions to the problem, that's not an issue. I'm just puzzled at what's going on.

Comment: @bolov What do you mean? The idea is to print non-alphabetic characters as is, but do stuff if it's an alphabetic character.

Comment: @ILoveYeezis What happen when you add the else?

Comment: @dreamcrash it just doesn't print anything, eventhough the condition of the `if` statement is fulfilled.

Comment: with `isalpha(plaintext[i] != 0)` you're doing one of ... `isalpha(0)` or `isalpha(1)`. I bet that is not what you want

Comment: @pmg How so? Afaik, I'm asking if `isalpha` returns 0, and if not, then proceed with `else`. Am I wrong or did I misunderstand?

Comment: `plaintext[i] != 0` is either `false` (`0`) or `true` (`1`) ... and you're doing `isalpha(<false or true>)` ... which will (very probably) return `false` (`0`) in both cases. ie... `isalpha(<boolean value>)` is always `false`

Comment: @pmg I edited the code in question to make it more obvious. My previous version was confusing, because I'd simplified it too much. Anyway I've fixed it and now it should be obvious that I intended to do two different things with `if` and `else`. The question still remains.

Comment: You have not described the problem adequately. You have not said whether the problem is your program will not compile or that it produces output different from you want and, if so, you have not shown sample input that reproduces the problem, the observed output, and the desired output. If there is code where you have the `//I intend…` comment, then the program will not compile because an `else` must immediately follow the statement attached to the `if`; you cannot have additional statements in between. (Statements inside `{ … }` would count as one statement.)…

Comment: … Do not show code that approximates the problem; we do not know what is actually in place of your `// I intend…` comment that relates to the problem. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. That should include **complete** code that can be compiled exactly as it is, no edits, to reproduce the problem. That does not have to be your entire program (you can reduce it), but it has to be enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, will do. I seem to have messed up indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for(i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if(isalpha(plaintext[i] != 0))
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        else
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
```

is the same as :

```
    for(i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)
        printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
```

because any logical operation may have two results: true and false. If in both cases you do exactly the same, why do you check the condition?

another problem :

```
if(isalpha(plaintext[i] != 0))
```

it should be

```
if(isalpha(plaintext[i]) != 0)
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to make it more obvious. I had simplified my code for the question but it seems it created more confusion lol, so now it's fixed.

Comment: The `!= 0` bit is redundant :-)

Comment: @pmg it is good for beginners as it makes things more obvious. I did some C courses for beginners over last two weeks and "shorthand" notation is very confusing for them :)

Comment: @0___________ Oh it was the brackets in the wrong place, that's what it was! That would've taken me ages to notice, haha.